# how to restrict the access on build.yml file from developers in Azure DevOps repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps we have created both build and release pipeline using classic way and now we are planning this to convert to yaml file.

But it seems in yaml method, the code can be put only on the root of the repo, where we want to keep the build yaml files in a separate repo, where the developers won't have access.

How can achieve this?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? Considering [accept one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which you think it is work for you.This could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread.  If you have any concern, feel free to share it here. Have a nice day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops), put in the main repo only the minimal `yaml` that refers to a template with all the steps, the template exits in another repo.

For example, your main repo `yaml`:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

jobs:
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

In in the repo: Contoso/BuildTemplates put the full `yaml`:

```
# Repo: Contoso/BuildTemplates
# File: common.yml
parameters:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu 16.04'

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
```

Restrict the access to the second repo (unless the agent pipeline user).

Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources) more info about the resources.

Comment: What if someone edit the yaml in the main repo to not use the template but a custom pipeline instead?

Comment: Of course you need to ass branch policy and check every change in the yaml during the PR.

Comment: But in the case that I have a pipeline build check in my PR, it will run with modified pipeline anyway, right? Or there is still a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that one solution could be the one proposed by @Shayki Abramczyk

but to have standalone *.yml in dedicated repository you can use 'git clone' while using 'Git Credentials' to access the other repository that contains the files you want to build by the pipeline.

If your repository dedicated for *.yml is in the same Azure Devops project then you should not have any problem with the release definition.

Please see example *.yml that works for us as described:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'your-preferred-image'

variables:
  solution: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/YourSolution.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
  urlWithCreds: 'https://YourUser:YourPassword@dev.azure.com/YourOrganization/YourProject/
    _git/YourOtherRepository'

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git --version
      git clone --quiet $(urlWithCreds)
      git checkout master

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: 'your build args'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to keep the YAML files in the root of the repository; ours are in a dedicated sub-folder:

[image: Example of a YAML pipeline file in a subfolder]

That's crucial, because it means that we can add a PR policy which restricts who can approve changes to any of the pipeline YAML files.

Comment: but how can restrict the permission on the subfolder from other developers?  Since its still residing the source code repo, while cloning the repo, the developers will get it right?

Comment: In this situation, you don't need to restrict permission - because with the right PR policy, **you** can control what changes go into master. For example you can define a policy which requires approval from someone in your team (not including the developers) on the files in the sub-folder, before they can be merged to master.